# How to pass several views return statements to one template in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, templates

Currently I have one template file that displays some graph results based on one Django view, however, I would like to display in this same template another set of results from another function view. These are the details:

**first function view** - This works OK, sending values to the second function view and rendering the results into the template.

```
@api_view(['GET','POST',])
def tickets_results_test(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        # ...do stuff...
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

    elif request.method == "POST":

        template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
        year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
        week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
        receive_send_year_week(year,week)
        ... rest of the code ...

        data = {
        "label_number_days": label_number_days,
        "days_of_data": count_of_days,
        }

        my_data = {'my_data': json.dumps(data)}
        return render(request, template_name, my_data)
```

**second function view** - I want to return these results into the template file.

```
def receive_send_year_week(year,week):
    return year, week
```

**template file** - I want to show the results from the second function view below the 

You are currently reviewing:

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html" %}

<script>
   {% block jquery %}

   var days_of_data = data.days_of_data 

   function setChart(){
    ....do stuff to generate graphs...
    ....
    }

 {% endblock %}
</script>

  {% block content %}    

   <div class='row'>
     <p>You are currently reviewing:</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10" url-endpoint='{% url "tickets_per_day_results" %}'>
        <div>
            <canvas id="tickets_per_day" width="850" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 {% endblock content %}
```

How can I display the results from the second function view inside of the template? Do I need to heavily modify the first view?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the second function; it just returns its arguments. And you ignore the return values anyway.

Comment: You can use a custom template tag to get new info in the template

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to return the arguments into the template html file. If this is not correct and the second function view is useless, how could I achieve my point?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. You *have* those values already in `tickets_results_test`. What's the point of passing them to a second function at all?

Comment: what do you want to do with year and week after you receive it from POST? the second function doesn't do anything, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to display those two values in the html, I want to write them in the html file. How can invoke them if you say that I already have them? @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display those two values in the html, I want to write them
>   in the html file. How can invoke them if you say that I already have
>   them?

You can simply place it in your data dict, this is, if the code you provided works partially, I can't test it right now, but you will get the gest of it:

```
template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)

data = {
  "label_number_days": label_number_days,
  "days_of_data": count_of_days,
  "year": year,
  "week": week,
}
```

Then in your template:

```
var year = data.year
var week = data.week
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want to do, altough it is not clear, as pointed by others.

Your view is an api view, so you might not be wanting to deal with a django template. You should probably make an Ajax call to this view and replace 'render' by [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/) in this case.

The other way is doing simple django stuff and use its template. So you should get rid of the 'if POST GET' and decorator parts (I don't see any POST request anyway) of your view, and  anywhere in your template use `{{my_data}}` to print your data. To access count_of _days define in the view, you can do `{{my_data.days_of_data}}`.

Things to undertstand here are:

- django template renders a html with data that you send through a dictionary (my_data). You can access this data with the double curly brackets notation in your template.
- Django views can be used as api endpoints. In that case you make an Ajax request and the view should return a json object to be handled by Ajax. No mention to any template whatsoever in the view.

Hope it helps!